# Search and replace on a specific line number in a shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have conf file.

```
dev 1 {
    #num-tx-queues 64
    #num-rx-queues 64
}

dev 2 {
    #num-tx-queues 64
    #num-rx-queues 64
}
..............................

dev 8 {
     #num-tx-queues 64
     #num-rx-queues 64
}
```

Note :- dotted line are for stack overflow in the file all 8 device exists
Except the dev number all are identical and commented out. Now parsing the env variable and if the dev exists replace it the value parsed.

I am passing the line number is sed to do the replacement but all the string are getting replaced as

```
dev 1 {
        num-tx-queues 72
        num-rx-queues 72
}

dev 2 {
        num-tx-queues 72
        num-rx-queues 72
}

...............

dev 8 {
        num-tx-queues 72
        num-rx-queues 72
}
```

Adding the code snippet for reference,

```
function vpp_startup_file_update()
{
    i=$1;shift
    echo "Inside vpp_startup_file_update"
    for param in $@
    do
       name=${param%%=*}
       value=${param#*=}
       case $name in
            num-rx-queues)
                local line=$((i+2))
                sed -i "$line, \$s/^        #${name} [0-9]*/        ${name} ${value}/" "$CONF_FILE_PATH"
            ;;
            num-tx-queues)
                local line=$((i+1))
                sed -i "$line, \$s/^        #${name} [0-9]*/        ${name} ${value}/" "$CONF_FILE_PATH"
            ;;
            num-tx-desc)
                local line=$((i+3))
                sed -i "$line, \$s/^        #${name} [0-9]*/        ${name} ${value}/" "$CONF_FILE_PATH"
            ;;
            num-rx-desc)
                local line=$((i+4))
                sed -i "$line, \$s/^        #${name} [0-9]*/        ${name} ${value}/" "$CONF_FILE_PATH"
            ;;
            *)
                echo "Parameter : $name value : $value does not match any case"
            ;;
       esac

    done
}

vpp_dpdk_dev_conf="dev=name=a,pci=2,mtu=1400,num-rx-queues=72,num-tx-queues=72,num-rx-desc=8,num-tx-desc=8,skip=false|true"
IFS=','

declare -a DEV=($vpp_dpdk_dev_conf)
for i in ${DEV[@]}; do
    for param in $(IFS='=';echo $i); do
        name=${param%% *}
        value=${param#* }
        cout=1
        case $name in
            pci)
                line_num=$(grep -Fn "dev $value" $CONF_FILE_PATH | cut --delimiter=":" --fields=1)
                vpp_startup_file_update $line_num "${DEV[@]}"
                break
            ;;
```

Any review is welcome,
Thanks
Niladri

Comment: I think you may be passing a range rather than a distinct line number. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses).

Comment: I tried adding i and the end of line variable but the same issue

Comment: Hi @xpusostomos, I am very much aware of the set -x mode and just printing the output of sed command, giving the context helps others also to approach it from another way round. For your reference I am giving the exact output of sed command local line=13
+ sed -i '13, $s/^        #num-rx-queues [0-9]*/        num-rx-queues 72/' /run/cvpp/vpp-startup.conf

Comment: It's not like you gave us the whole script with instructions to run it. You gave us garbage to solve what ought to be a trivial sed question. I copied your original conf file, and ran it through your sed command above and it only changes the last occurrence to 72, and the rest remained 64. Instead of doing the whole very hack-like calculation of line numbers, I'd be using the ed editor, searching for dev XX, and then searching for num-tx-queues or whatever, then doing your line substution. much more robust against a conf file that happens to have non standard spacing.

Comment: You need to post an [mcve].  What your input file is, what your output file is currently and what output file you want at the end.  We are left guessing at this point.  You could do this with `awk`, but without an exact desired output, I do not want to waste time.